# How do I make a div element float out of its container, when the tag is inside the container

Tags: html, css, web

I have a container inside body, this container has left right margins and width. Now there is a div inside this that stretches throughout the page outside of container, but the tag is inside container. How do I achieve this.

Picture for illustration[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute positioning:

```css
#overflowing-bar {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

This will only work, of course, if the container is statically positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="overflower">
        Overflow.
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#container {
background: #f0f0f0;
width: 300px; 
margin: 0px auto;  
height: 300px;    
position: relative;
}

#overflower {
 width: 500px;
 position: absolute;
 left: -30%;
 top: 30%;  
 background: green; 
 text-align: center;
 color: white;   
}
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/QwCq5/

Answer (score 0):

Relative positioning would also work, though it means hardcoding the margin widths: http://jsfiddle.net/H7YJR/

Answer (score 0):

If space at the left and at the right has fixed width, you can you negative margins for inner block:

```
.inner {margin: 0 -100px; position: relative; }
```

where `100px` is width of space at the left and at the right of container.

`position: relative` usually used in conjunction with negative margins to make sure that shifted parts of block are visible.

Answer (score 0):

You just give the inner container negative left and right margin. It must be equal to left and right margin of outer container. Try and play with this example (I gave outer div a `heigth` attribute, that you can see what's going on):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-color: #F60;
}
#inner_div {
    background-color: #3399FF;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="inner_div">test</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```